# Why does first slideshow image click skip transition and go straight to image?

Tags: html, css

In the slideshow shown below, there are two images available. Once clicking on a button for the second image after first opening my page, there is a sudden jump to that image with no 5 second transition as expected. Also when doing this, I notice that `#slideshowimage-2` is shown in the url (doing this offline) after clicking the button for that image. Here's the code below:

CSS:

```
.slideshowcontainer {
width:800px;
height:400px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:0px;
text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
top:30px;
border-style:solid;
    border-width:10px;
border-color:white;
border-radius:15px;
}     


.imagecontainer {
width:1800px;
height:400px;
clear: both;
position:relative;
-webkit-transition:left 3s;
-moz-transition:left 3s;
-o-transition:left 3s;
-ms-transition:left 3s;
transition:left 3s;
animation:scroller 16s infinite;
}


@keyframes scroller {
0% {transform:translateX(0);}
31.25% {transform:translateX(0);}
50% {transform:translateX(-800px);}
    81.25% {transform:translateX(-800px);}
    100% {transform:translateX(0);}
}


.slideshowimage {
float:left;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    position:relative;
}


@keyframes change {
0% {
    transform: translateX(-800px);
}
100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    animation: scroller 16s infinite;
}
}

@keyframes change2 {
0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
}
100% {
    transform: translateX(-800px);
    animation: scroller2 16s infinite;
}
}



#slideshowimage-1:target ~ .imagecontainer {
animation: none;
transform: translateX(0px);
animation: change 3s forwards;
}

#slideshowimage-2:target ~ .imagecontainer {
animation: none;
transform: translateX(-800px);
animation: change2 3s forwards;
}


.buttoncontainer {
position:relative;
top:-20px;
}


.button {
display:inline-block;
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    background-color:darkgray;
-webkit-transition:background-color 0.25s;
    -moz-transition:background-color 0.25s;
    -o-transition:background-color 0.25s;
-ms-transition:background-color 0.25s;
    transition:background-color 0.25s;
}


.button:hover {
background-color:gray;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slideshowcontainer">
  <span id="slideshowimage-1"></span>
  <span id="slideshowimage-2"></span>
  <span id="slideshowimage-3"></span>
  <div class="imagecontainer">
    <a href="#"><img src="WebServiceSlide.png" class="slideshowimage" style="width:800px;height:400px;"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="es-flag.png" class="slideshowimage" style="width:800px;height:400px;"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="buttoncontainer">
    <a href="#slideshowimage-1" class="button"></a>
    <a href="#slideshowimage-2" class="button"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

How could I make it so that the transition set upon clicking a button occurs on the first click? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason:-**

Because the `left` and `translateX` both are different. If you apply `left:-800px` when slide is at `translateX(-800px)` (2nd slide) then animation will continue at the 2nd part of slideshow. Thats why you are seeing a blank white space(when `translateX(-800px)` accors when it is already `left:-800px`).

**Solution:-**

You either have to use `translateX` or `left`. use the same in all the places

**Part of code that solved the problem:-**

```
@keyframes change {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-800px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
        animation: scroller 16s infinite;
    }
}

@keyframes change2 {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-800px);
        animation: scroller2 16s infinite;
    }
}

#slideshowimage-1:target ~ .imagecontainer {
    animation: none;
    transform: translateX(0px);
    animation: change 3s forwards;
}

#slideshowimage-2:target ~ .imagecontainer {
    animation: none;
    transform: translateX(-800px);
    animation: change2 3s forwards;
}
```

**Explanation:-**

This code doesn't do `translateX` manually. Instead it uses animation to scoll single time by `animation: change 3s forwards;`

**Drawback:-**

Once we click on the slide selection button the animation stops. I have even tried it to solve by adding animation in the `change` keyframes animate end section. But unfortunately it didn't work. So I would suggest an alternate method to overcome the drawback as follows

> To overcome the drawback I have added a play button which
>   will replay the slideshow animation which got paused by the slide
>   button. (Once we click on play button it takes a little time to slide
>   as we have given 16s in animation)

**DEMO:-**

```css
.slideshowcontainer {
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-color: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.imagecontainer {
    width: 1800px;
    height: 400px;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 3s;
    -moz-transition: all 3s;
    -o-transition: all 3s;
    -ms-transition: all 3s;
    transition: all 3s;
    transform: translateX(0px);
    animation: scroller 16s infinite;
}

@keyframes scroller {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    31.25% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateX(-800px);
    }
    81.25% {
        transform: translateX(-800px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes scroller2 {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-800px);
    }
    31.25% {
        transform: translateX(-800px);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    81.25% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-800px);
    }
}


@keyframes change {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-800px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
        animation: scroller 16s infinite;
    }
}

@keyframes change2 {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-800px);
        animation: scroller2 16s infinite;
    }
}

.slideshowimage {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

#slideshowimage-1:target ~ .imagecontainer {
    animation: none;
    transform: translateX(0px);
    animation: change 3s forwards;
}

#slideshowimage-2:target ~ .imagecontainer {
    animation: none;
    transform: translateX(-800px);
    animation: change2 3s forwards;
}

#slideshowimage-3:target ~ .imagecontainer {
    transform: translateX(0);
    animation: scroller 16s infinite;
}

.buttoncontainer {
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
}

.button {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: darkgray;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.25s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.25s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.25s;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.25s;
    transition: background-color 0.25s;
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: gray;
}

.buttonplay:after {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    content: ' ';
    border-left: solid 13px darkgray;
    border-top: solid 8px transparent;
    border-bottom: solid 8px transparent;
    }
```

```html
<div class="slideshowcontainer">
    <span id="slideshowimage-1"></span>
    <span id="slideshowimage-2"></span>
    <span id="slideshowimage-3"></span>
        <div class="imagecontainer">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://placehold.it/800x400" class="slideshowimage" style="width:800px;height:400px;"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="https://placehold.it/900x450" class="slideshowimage" style="width:800px;height:400px;"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="buttoncontainer">
            <a href="#slideshowimage-1" class="button"></a>
            <a href="#slideshowimage-2" class="button"></a>
            <a href="#slideshowimage-3" class="buttonplay"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: So how would I actually change the transitions to animations on the button click?

Comment: I have added a play button will play animation. The slider button will stop the animation and make the transition. The play button will replay the animation by assigning a new animation

Comment: Please actually read my question. That is clearly not what I asked for. There is not point in me repeating it, just read the original post for a better understanding. Thank you.

Comment: I am not repeating it. I have done a different thing here (I just used the same images). Here check the button. The transition works even for the first time. And I have added the reason in the answer. Read the reason carefully.

Comment: I have no intention of using a play button, thank you. What is it that you did so that clicking the second slide for the first time doesn't make an abrupt jump? Which part of the code has resolved this? Furthermore, you have gotten rid of the automatic animation unless the user click the 'play' button, how could I keep the first click transition/animation and the automatic animation at the same time? Please answer the first question before the one I just asked, because I can't even tell what you did to make the first click successful. Many thanks.

Comment: I have added that part of code block in the answer. This code doesn't do translateX manually. Instead it uses animation to scoll single time by `animation: change 3s forwards;`. **I want to tell you one trick here**. When the button clicked we need to change different animation to trigger animate.

Comment: Certainly an improvement, much appreciated. Now the only issue left is that fact that when I click the first button on the first image as the page first loads, it jumps to the second image then transitions back to the first. After the first click, things are fine how could I resolve this? See my updated code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128543/discussion-between-jafarbtech-and-h3ll0).